# How to Use 100% intel core i9 CPU with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intel, cpu-usage, processor, amd-processor

I have tested with Ryzen 5900X, Visual Studio uses 100% processing and compiles my Source code in 103 seconds. But on another PC with intel core i9 12900K processor, it takes 228 seconds to compile, because it only uses 45% of processing power.

I have tried with 'Cinebench' Benchmark software, my processor usage reaches 100%. Means there is no setting blocking my PC to reach its full potential and all cores are unparked. Seems like, Visual Studio Settings need some tweaks. any help would be highly appreciated. thanks.

Windows 10, intel core-i9 12900K, 16 core, 24 Logical processors, 128 GB RAM, 2 TB SSD, RTX 3090 Ti.

Comment: try setting *"maxium number parallel projects build"* under `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run` to increase that number. For a i9 12900K CPU  which could be as high as 24

Comment: its value is already 24

Comment: Probably should post more system details like OS, memory size, memory speed, HD throughput, HD type... etc etc As it stands you are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Added system details, I have tested with benchmark tool, it is capable of using 100% CPU. earlier I was also thinking that maybe processors are parked or maybe my power supply watts could be the reason.